# how to fullscreen my game using pygame in Python 3.3?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

In Python2.7 I could use pygame.display.set_mode((x,y),FULLSCREEN,32) to fullscreen my game.
But in Python 3.3 the FULLSCREEN is not defined in pygame and I couldn't find the right number to achieve it.
Also,I could not find the right way to use pygame.event.set_blocked().

Answer (score 0):

You have to use pygame.FULLSCREEN instead of just FULLSCREEN.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([0,0], pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

About the set_blocked case, basically you will be blocking an event from happening. For example, just to illustrate I can ask user before game loop if he/she wants to use mouse or keyboard.

```
value = input("mouse or keyboard: ")
    if value == "m":
        pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.KEYDOWN)

    else:
        pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
```

And in event loop, pygame will ignore the blocked component.

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        player.jump(current_level.wall_list)

if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            player.jump(current_level.wall_list)
```